# Postgresql uuid_generate_v5 using Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I'm attempting to use [Arel](http://github.com/rails/arel) to construct a query like:

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_url(),CONCAT('hello', 'world')) # 3fc82e1a-b051-595a-8564-27a096716d37
```

So far I have the following:

```
composite_keys = ['hello', 'world']
quoted_composite_keys = composite_keys.map do |composite_key|
  Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(composite_key)
end

concat = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat', quoted_composite_keys)
uuid_ns_url = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('uuid_ns_url', [])
uuid_generate_v5 = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('uuid_generate_v5', [uuid_ns_url, concat]).as('uuid')
select_statement = Arel::SelectManager.new(ActiveRecord::Base, project: uuid_generate_v5)
```

However when doing `select_statement.to_sql` I get the following error:

> *** RuntimeError Exception: unsupported: Hash
>
> nil

It looks like the problem is that I'm not exactly sure what to pass to `select` in regards to what to project.

Anyone done something similar to this using Arel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I need to use a slightly different syntax when creating my `SelectManager`:

```
select_statement = Arel::SelectManager.new(ActiveRecord::Base).project(uuid_generate_v5)
```